# DB snapshot not appearing under elastic beanstalk list of snapshots

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk has a feature where you can couple an RDS database to an environment and create one from a snapshot. Originally, my problem was that AWS wouldn't let me select my database snapshot because the DB engine (postgres 10.16) was out of date.

So I navigated to a separate but similar RDS database, upgraded the DB engine to 14.4, and created a snapshot of that.

Now though when I go to create my database from a snapshot back in beanstalk, the newly created snapshot doesn't appear in my list of snapshots. I am using the online AWS console to perform these actions.

How do I get my environment to use a database built from my upgraded engine snapshot?

I tried using the AWS online console and was met with the above behavior. I then tried using `eb deploy` from the command line, modifying `.ebextension` files. You can see my relevant settings here:

```
option_settings:
  aws:rds:dbinstance:
    DBInstanceClass: db.t3.medium
    DBSnapshotIdentifier: <snapshot-name>
```

However, this didn't affect my database. I made sure too that the `DBInstanceClass` was the same one as the RDS database from which the snapshot was created, and added the `DBAllocatedStorage` key, too, but no changes in behavior.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

UPDATE: I went to the old, visible in the snapshot menu snapshot, and just upgraded the engine version there in RDS. I then went back to elastic beanstalk and could no longer see *that* snapshot anymore, which is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

So I still have no idea why on the web console my snapshot wasn't appearing, or why on the CLI modifying `.ebextensions` did not work for my created instance that didn't have a database enabled.

However, it appears that if you create a new environment from the CLI using `DBSnapshotIdentifier` in `.ebextensions` as stated in my question, you're able to use any snapshot you want, even if it has an old engine.

The command `eb create <env_name> --database.instance db.t3.medium --database.username postgres --database.password <pass>`, adding in my other non-database flags, worked for me.